# Nouveau GPU lockup error while updating

Tags: gpu, nouveau

Installed Ubuntu, updates installed.

Clicked in the search lens, then the [image: system froze here]

It hung there for about 15 minutes and then got out, [image: here is the message]:

Comment: Seems like you're GPU froze up (`nouveau GPU lockup`). You might try installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'am using Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I suggest you try installing a proprietary driver. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers

Answer (score 2):

Boot using live disc. Hold down shift to get to boot options. You should get a menu to try Ubuntu before installing, Install to disc etc etc.

Hit F6 and choose nomodset, then press escape.

Choose the boot option you want.

If you get in then you will likely need install the proprietary driver for you card.

[Here is a translation for you](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0.%20%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0.%20%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20Ubuntu%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%2C%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82.%D0%B4.%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82.%D0%B4.%20%0A%0A%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20F6%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20nomodset%2C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3.%20%0A%0A%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5.%20%0A%0A%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%2C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B.).

Comment: Oh boy... translate.google.com can help you immensely..!!

Comment: And where are the users of Ubuntu supposed to go who are using it in another language. Okay..this might be english site, but atleast everybody has the right to put their question. Don't answer it if you can't even try to translate to understand.

Comment: No one minds if you provide a link to a google translation, but it does not belong in the question/answer.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is a site to help people, not shoo them away...we should help every body if possible. We are a community for a reason.

Comment: That's why it is ok for you to provide a link to a translation, but it *does not* belong in the answer itself.